# Requisição post retorna erro 500

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests, servidor

tenho um script simples em Python que envia uma requisição post com uma determinada payload mas ele retorna erro 500.
Gostaria muito que alguém me ajudasse.

O código:

```
def answered(self,answer):
    headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "apikey": "<API KEY HERE>",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "69",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "device-Id": "b0fa2eee-66ba-4b23-99fe-c2cfeee7cc70",
    "Host": "giga.unitel.ao",
    "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT",
    "Origin": "http://giga.unitel.ao",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Referer": "http://giga.unitel.ao/",
    "token": "<TOKEN HERE>",
    "txId": "d9f98598-0251-4319-88ed-ef729ec872ec",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36",

    }
    payload = {
        "moveId":4628870481,
        "index":1,
        "help":"null",
        "time": 20,
        "optional":"null"
    }
    answer = requests.post("http://giga.unitel.ao/api/game/answer",data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(answer)
```

**URL** do portal: http://giga.unitel.ao

Comment: @imonferrari, eis outra questão!

Comment: Erro 500 é erro de servidor. Você pode apontar para a documentação da API deste site?

Answer (score 1):

Alguma coisa no headers deve estar errado. Tente deixá-lo com o mínimo possível, conforme abaixo, para questões de teste.

```
headers = {
    "apikey": "<API TESTE HERE>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "device-Id": "b0fa2eee-66ba-4b23-99fe-c2cfeee7cc70",
    "token": "<TOKEN HERE>",
    "txId": "d9f98598-0251-4319-88ed-ef729ec872ec",
}

payload = {
    "moveId": 4628870481,
    "index": 1,
    "help": "null",
    "time": 20,
    "optional": "null"
}


answer = requests.post("http://giga.unitel.ao/api/game/answer", data=payload, headers=headers)
print(answer.json())
```

A resposta obtida foi:

```
{'responseData': {'errorCode': 'INVALID_TOKEN', 'errorMessage': 'Invalid token.'}, 'responseCode': '400', 'inError': True, 'requestId': 'd9f98598-0251-4319-88ed-ef729ec872ec', 'additionalFields': {}}
```

Trabalhe a partir daqui. Acredito que alguma coisa excedente no header esteja gerando o erro no servidor.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: _"Alguma coisa no headers deve estar errado"_ isso provavelmente é o motivo, mas só do servidor retornar 500 que significa erro interno do servidor já sugere que os caras programaram a API igual o nariz deles, tinham é que validar os parâmetros passados e se houver algum problema neles retomar o código apropriado do protocolo HTTP para isso, que eu não lembro qual é agora, deve ser 4xx alguma coisa. Apesar que pode ser outros motivos, uma falha no acesso ao banco de dados, por exemplo.

Comment: @Piovezan, concordo que "quebrar" o servidor por header incompatível é problema de programação na API...